# Leaflet layer repeating itself on Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I'm building a leaflet map on an Angular project which consists of a single layer in PNG format. It comes from a GeoSever and it uses the WMS protocol as you can see on the url.

**home.component.html**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { Map } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  var url = '.../.../wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=(...)format=image%2Fpng';

  const map = new Map('map').setView([39.46975, -0.37739], 1);
  L.tileLayer(url, {attribution: 'Lab'}).addTo(map);
}
```

[image: Map duplicating layer with setView zoom at 1]

As you can see the layer keeps repeating itself for no reason and it doesn't even adjust to its div container.

I've noticed that it duplicates the layer the more zoom I set on the setView method (if I set 0, it creates 1 row of infinite layers, if I set 1, it creates 2 rows, if I set 2 it creates 4 rows, 3, 8 rows, 4, 16 rows, 5, 32 rows...).

What can I do to stop Leaflet from duplicating it and show only a single image of the layer?

Comment: Read https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html .

Comment: Thank you. Am I supposed to see maps on the web? I followed it but I can't see any map on my project now nor the web, though the maps are there as I can see the attributions and controls. https://gyazo.com/c87620537919a07b9ed407f96d4e074f